# Como Testar Formulários com o Cypress?

Tags: javascript, formulário, testes-automatizados, cypress

Estou com uma certa dificuldade em entender como funcionam os testes de formulários com utilizando o Cypress.

Gostaria de testar se o form da página `https://drbarakat.curseria.com/e-book` está redirecionando para a página `https://drbarakat.curseria.com/e-book/obrigado`.

Até agora, consegui rodar o teste, mas desconfio que ao invés de dar o submit, o Cypress simplesmente "força" um redirect, pois ao chegar na segunda página (`https://drbarakat.curseria.com/e-book/obrigado`) aparece o seguinte erro:

> chainers.split is not a function

Meu código do teste até agora está assim :

```
// <reference types="cypress" />

context('Actions', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {

        Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
            // returning false here prevents Cypress from
            // failing the test
            return false
          })

      cy.visit('https://drbarakat.curseria.com/e-book',  { force: true })
    })
  
      it('.submit() - submit a form', () => {
        // https://on.cypress.io/submit
        

        cy.get('#_form_95_')
        .find('input[name="fullname"]').type('teste')

        cy.get('#_form_95_')
        .find('input[name="email"]').type('teste@performmaonline.com')
    
        cy.get('#_form_95_').submit()
          .next().should(cy.visit('https://drbarakat.curseria.com/e-book/obrigado'))
      })

     
  })
```

Ele está de fato fazendo o submit com êxito ou está simplesmente forçando um redirect? Nunca fiz nenhum teste assim antes.

Answer (score 2):

Sou uma usuária nova do Cypress e na automação de testes no geral, mas pude notar duas coisas que podem estar causando a interferência no seu código.

1. Você está usando um `cy.visit()` dentro do `should()` e isso está direcionando para a página `https://drbarakat.curseria.com/e-book/obrigado`. Tente usar o `cy.url().should(...)` para testar se a página acessada é a esperada. [Documentação do `cy.url()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html#Syntax).
2. O erro "*chainers.split is not a function*" provavelmente está sendo causado pela chamada do `next()` antes do `should()`. O `next()` é um comando que retorna o próximo elemento baseado no `cy.get()`. [Documentação do `next()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/next.html#Syntax).

O `submit()`, segundo a documentação do Cypress não é um comando de interação direta com o DOM. Acredito que o Cypress usa o elemento com tipo "`submit`" dentro do form pois o comando só interage com elementos form. [Documentação do `submit`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/submit.html#Rules).